# Verify the value of label in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, assertions

I am creating automation for for product prchase process for different countires. On order confirmation page I am veriying if tax price and shipping price is set to 0 or not.

Here is my code:

```
String expectedshippingprice = "$0.00"; 
String actualshipingprice = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div/fieldset/div[2]/div[2]")).getText(); 

Assert.assertEquals("Verify Shipping Price", expectedshippingprice, actualshipingprice);
```

But I am getting error :

> java.lang.AssertionError: $0.00 expected [$0.00] but found [Verify
>   Price]

Here is is the HTML code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs-8 col-lg-8">Product Price</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">$19.95</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-8 col-lg-8">Shipping</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">$0.00</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xs-8 col-lg-8">Tax</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">$0.00</div>
</div>
```

Please help!

Comment: Could you point us to the actual webpage you are dealing with?

Comment: That's awfully brittle. I would recommend assigning IDs or classes to your elements and using those to select; better yet, use a proper table.

Comment: **`Assert.assertEquals`** is working for me. Are you sure you are not making any other mistake?

Comment: 1. xpath used is poor, please share the link to the site 
2. cannot find "verify price" in the html still, please share more of the html to provide details

Answer (score 1):

Provided you properly imported `org.junit.Assert` (and not some other `Assert`), function

```
 Assert.assertEquals(message, expected, actual);
```

will return AssertionException like this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: <message> expected [<expected>] but found [<actual>]
```

So based on your exception (`java.lang.AssertionError: $0.00 expected [$0.00] but found [Verify Price].`), I can conclude that you called `assertEquals` like this:

```
 Assert.assertEquals(expectedshippingprice, actualshipingprice, "Verify Price");
```

Although your question shows the right way. So just change the order of parameters in the same way as your question currently shows:

```
Assert.assertEquals("Verify Shipping Price", expectedshippingprice, actualshipingprice);
```

Comment: I changed the order as:
Assert.assertEquals(actualshipingprice, "$0.00"); 
Its working fine. 

Thank you guys!